# Advanced Custom Field DatePicker

Tags: plugins, themes, templates

I am using Advanced custom field + Advanced Forms (Fabian Lindfors) for appointment form. I am wondering whats the best approach to dynamically disable first two weeks in datepicker? For example if I fill in the form on the 6 Feb 2018 and the date picker only allow me to pick a date only after two weeks.

Comment: I found the solution. Using already installed Contact 7 and use snippet  [date* appointment min:today+14days] which block out the first two weeks in the calender. Works like a charm.